# Generating HMAC::SHA256.hexdigest in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wonder, what's method equivalent to HMAC::SHA256.hexdigest in Ruby? I ran through http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SHA-1.6.4.1/docs/Data-Digest-Pure-SHA.html but had trouble figuring it out. In Ruby it can be used as:

```
HMAC::SHA256.hexdigest(secret, nonce.to_s +client_id + api_key)
```

Comment: Besides @Sibi's answer, which uses the [`SHA` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SHA), you could also take a look at the [`cryptohash` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptohash), which covers *many* more hashes than just SHA-1 and SHA-2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `Crypto.HMAC` from the crypto-api:

```
Crypto.Hash.CryptoAPI Crypto.HMAC> hmac (MacKey "hello") "goodbye" :: SHA512
SHA512 "V]\163\146\166M\199\DLE\201\&5\163\DC17LF\246\150>\141\\*\197Q\198\203\233\235\&1&\b\245\SI\172Zc.\243\218\243\&9\224\172\215y\179|\240L\137\192M \167f\246\235\FS\188\231P(\245\ETXZ"
```

EDIT: The exact same code can produce the HMAC for other hashes thanks to the functions used being polymorphic.  For example:

```
> simpleHex $ encode (hmac (MacKey "hello") "goodbye" :: SHA256)
"81 48 a0 89  d1 69 a8 9a  3e f0 b2 2a  6e b9 ab c1  d5 7e 70 73  a7 37 c9 0a  03 78 cf 2c  4e 39 94 de"
```

(Notice the optional-but-pretty use of encoding from the `cereal` package and hex output from `simple-hex`)

Comment: why did you use sha512 instead of sha256 like in my question, by the way?

Comment: I recalled your question asked about HMAC but not a particular hash.  Just change the type signature to change the hash - the functions are polymorphic thanks to the classes from crypto-api.

Answer (score 7):

This sample code works (using the https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SHA) library):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Digest.Pure.SHA

main = do
  let a = sha256 "some test message"
      b = hmacSha256 "key" "some test message"
  mapM_ print [showDigest a, showDigest b]
```

Demo in ghci:

```
λ> main
"3cb0603701548a84d3e7408a805e270a094000f537b96a6e83a36271a3ff192f"
"a5a36db81683537aacf8b6283121ffdb949ece609abbfe8a5fbc91cc76031edd"
```

Comment: what's the difference between "a" and "b"?

Comment: They are both just variables.  `a` is bound to the SHA-256 hash of `"some test messages"` while `b is bound to the HMAC you see specified on the next line.  variables can be any text starting with a lower-case letter so long as they omit certain symbols and aren't keywords.

Comment: I re-phrase: what's the meaning of "a" and "b"?

Comment: @Grienders `a` contains 256 SHA of the message. `b` contains [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

Comment: and which one should I use?

Comment: @Grienders It depends on what you need ? If you just need simple hash function, use `sha256`. If you need keyed hash message, then use `hmacSha256`. That said, I'm not an expert in cryptography domain.

Comment: I need whatever is equivalent to code in my question.

Comment: so which one should I use?

Comment: @Grienders You need to use `hmacSha256` as that's what you use in your Ruby code.